# Nginx Specific Redirect Rules

Tags: nginx, redirect, subdomain

I'm trying to read all the suggestions and tips that are present in this forum but I cant find a way to make this rule work. I want that if a specific url is requested that nginx redirect permanently to a subdomain:

```
if ($host = 'www.domain.com/zh/')

    redirect www.cn.domain.com$requested_uri
```

The syntax its not correct but its only to give the main idea, I only want that `/zh/` jump to sub domain, the other like `/en/`, `/jp/`, etc. I don't want nginx make any redirect.

Thank you very much, all help will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty easy. You don't even need `if`.

```
rewrite ^/zh/(.*) http://www.cn.example.com/$1 permanent;
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you very much for the big help. Just one more question, if I can. What site or posts do you recommend regarding the nginx security, rules, pitfalls, etc? Thank you very much.

Comment: The nginx wiki?

Comment: Thank you very much! I found this one http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-unix-bsd-nginx-webserver-security.html , maybe can useful to other users.